# The ComputeSignature method of System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs works on localhost but not on an azure app service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, backend

I am developing a c# web api. And I added a class library to connect to an external web service. And to log in to that resource, the following method is executed:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Firma mensaje
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="messageBytes">Bytes del mensaje</param>
        /// <param name="signerCertificate">Certificado usado para firmar</param>
        /// <returns>Bytes del mensaje firmado</returns>
        /// <remarks></remarks>
        public static byte[] SignMessageBytes(byte[] messageBytes, X509Certificate2 signerCertificate)
        {
            const string ID_FNC = "[FirmaBytesMensaje]";
            try
            {
                // Pongo el mensaje en un objeto ContentInfo (requerido para construir el obj SignedCms)
                var contentInfo = new ContentInfo(messageBytes);
                var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);

                // Creo objeto CmsSigner que tiene las caracteristicas del firmante
                var cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(signerCertificate)
                {
                    IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly
                };

                if (VerboseMode) Console.WriteLine(ID_FNC + "***Firmando bytes del mensaje...");
                // Firmo el mensaje PKCS #7
                signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);

                if (VerboseMode) Console.WriteLine(ID_FNC + "***OK mensaje firmado");
                // Encodeo el mensaje PKCS #7.
                return signedCms.Encode();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ID_FNC + "***Error al firmar: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This works perfectly in localhost environment. But when I publish it to an Azure app service it fails with the error:
`The system cannot find the file specified.`
In the line

```cs
signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner);
```

don't know what the reason could be. If anyone has information about any extra configuration that the app service needs, it would be of great help to me. Thank you so much!

Getting the SignMessageBytes method to work in the Azure environment

Answer (score 0):

try as below code changes:

```
// Find the certificate by thumbprint
X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
    "your-thumbprint",
    false
);

if (certs.Count > 0)
{
    X509Certificate2 signerCertificate = certs[0];
    // Continue with signing using signerCertificate
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Certificate not found.");
}
```

replace "your-thumbprint" with the actual thumbprint of your certificate.